# MySql posts between specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I want to select statuses where their post date passed 6 hours but now 12 hours.
Exampe:

Now 20.02.2020 23:00:00

Post date 20.02.2020 16:00:00

- (Now - Post date) > 6
- (Now - Post date) < 12

Basically, what I want is:

> 6<(now-post_date)<12

I am trying this code below,

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    offers INNER JOIN status ON offers.offer_id=status.offer_id         
WHERE status.status_id IN(SELECT 
                               MAX(status.status_id) 
                          FROM status 
                          GROUP BY status.offer_id) 
    AND status.status_code IN(1, 2) 
    AND 6*60*60 < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - offers.offer_datePosted) 
    AND 12*60*60 > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - offers.offer_datePosted)
```

What is my mistake here?
Thanks in advance!

[image: tables]

Comment: Can you please post an example table and expected table which would help to understand the problem easier?

Comment: `WHERE offers.offer_datePosted BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 12 HOUR AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 6 HOUR`. *What is my mistake here?* Datetime values cannot be substracted.

Comment: date_add(offers.offer_datePosted,interval 6 hours) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND date_add(offers.offer_datePosted,interval 12 hours) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: Hi @sveer, added.

Comment: Try this first and see what it is returning - SELECT * FROM offers where date_add(offers.offer_datePosted,interval 6 hours) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND date_add(offers.offer_datePosted,interval 12 hours) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYıldırım what I meant was a table that we can see and understand the data (both given table and expected table). Table defintion doesnt really help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check the time.

```
AND NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR < offers.offer_datePosted 
AND NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR > offers.offer_datePosted
```

This will add the hours corretly

Comment: Don't work How? could you show some data in sql fiddle  Did you check if all max status_id even have that timeframe in your database?